# Why does adding to the $x$ variable cause a function transformation to the left?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So I was reading this PDF on function transformation and here's how they explained it. Say you have an original function

$$ f(x_1) =y_1 $$

then you add "$h$" to get

$$ f(x+h) $$

Now if you substitute $x$ with $x-h$ the function becomes

$$ f((x-h)+h) = f(x_1) = y_1 $$

I understand how this works, now that we have a new input $x-h$ yet the $y$ value is unchanged we end up with a new $x$ value that is less so we moved left,  however I have a few questions:

Where does the idea of inserting $x-h$ for $x$ come from, what justifies us making this substitution.

Are we making a substitution so that we can arrive at a unchanged $y$ value? So basically we are asking what can we input that will leave the $y$ value unchanged. We want to do this so we keep the $y$ values the same but change the $x$ values

Comment: We define a new function g(x)=f(x+h), for some fixed value h.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You can look at it as a translation.

A basic purpose of a translation is to have a similar looking graph shifted by some units. So let's say $f(x)$ translated by $k$ units in the positive $x$-direction gives you $g(x)$, you would want to have some $\epsilon$ that will give you $g(x)=f(x+\epsilon)$ for all input in the defined domain.

Now we need to find what exactly that $\epsilon$ is. Suppose we have a point $\left(0,f(0)\right)$. It will be translated to $\left(k,f(0)\right)$. The point $\left(1,f(1)\right)$. It will be translated to $\left(k+1,f(1)\right)$ and so on. This means that a point $\left(x,f(x)\right)$. It will be translated to $\left(x+k,f(x)\right)$.

Now we can establish that $f(x)$ is in fact equal to $g(x+k)$. Hence it also means that $f(x-k)=g(x)$.

And that's how a translation of $h$ units in the positive $x$-direction on $y=f(x)$ gives you $y=f(x-h)$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and explain it to me. I follow along up to the point $(x+k, f(x))$ but I don't see how $f(x) = g(x+k)$

Comment: The translated point has coordinates $(x+k,g(x+k))$ and the same point happens to have $y$-coordinate of $f(x)$ so we can then equate $f(x)=g(x+k)$.